Show that there exist $F_1, F_2 \in \left (\mathbb R^n \right )^{\ast}$ such that $|F_1 (x)| + |F_2 (x)| \leq \|x\|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$

Let $X = \mathbb R^n$ and $Y \subseteq X$ be a subspace of $X.$ Let $f_1, f_2 \in Y^{\ast}$ be such that $\left \lvert f_1 (y) \right \rvert + \left \lvert f_2 (y) \right \rvert \leq \|y\|$ for all $y \in Y.$ Using Hahn-Banach extension theorem show that there exist $F_1, F_2 \in X^{\ast}$ such that for all $y \in Y$ $$F_1 (y) = f_1 (y),\ F_2 (y) = f_2 (y),$$ and, $$\left \lvert F_1 (x) \right \rvert + \left \lvert F_2 (x) \right \rvert \leq \|x\|$$ for all $x \in X.$

My Attempt $:$ Clearly $\|f_j \| \leq 1$ for $j = 1,2.$ By Hahn-Banach extension theorem we can get hold of norm preserving extensions $F_1, F_2 \in X^{\ast}.$ But that only guarantees $|F_1(x)| + |F_2 (x)| \leq 2 \|x\|$ for all $x \in X,$ which is not what I intended to show. Any small hint would be appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

This one took me a little too long to figure out, but since you asked for a hint, I'll give you one: Apply Hahn-Banach to $f_1 + f_2$ and $f_1 - f_2$, retaining their norms. I'm happy to write a full answer on request. Also happy, if you figure it out, for you to self-answer your question (and I'll up-vote your answer).

I still get the bound $2|x|$. Please post an answer. I am curious. @TheoBendit

I just noticed you aren't the OP, @geetha290krm Ah well, I'll spoil the puzzle for everyone. :-)

Why don't you ask a separate question about the complex case?

Recall that $|a| + |b| = \max\{a + b, a - b, b - a, -a - b\} = \max\{|a + b|, |a - b|\}$. With this in mind, let $g_1 = f_1 + f_2$, and $g_2 = f_1 - f_2$. Then $|f_1(y)| + |f_2(y)| \le \|y\|$ holds if and only if $|g_1(y)| \le \|y\|$ and $|g_2(y)| \le \|y\|$. So, the condition on $f_1$ and $f_2$ holds if and only if $\|g_1\|$ and $\|g_2\|$ have norm at most $1$.
Use Hahn-Banach to find extensions $G_1, G_2$ over $X$, of $g_1$ and $g_2$ respectively, retaining their norms, and define
$$\begin{align}
F_1 &= \frac{G_1 + G_2}{2} \\
F_2 &= \frac{G_1 - G_2}{2} \\
\end{align}$$
Note that $f_1(y) = F_1(y)$ and $f_2(y) = F_2(y)$, and since $\|G_1\|, \|G_2\| \le 1$ with $G_1 = F_1 + F_2$ and $G_2 = F_1 - F_2$, we must correspondingly have $|F_1(x)| + |F_2(x)| \le \|x\|$ for all $x$.

Beautifully done! Thanks a lot for your inputs. Sorry for the late reply. I was busy with some of my works. Thanks again.

Thanks. It is in the very last step that I goofed up and got $2|x||$ as the bound. Your idea is really nice.

Thank you, both of you. :-)

I wonder if the corresponding result for the complex case is true.

@geetha290krm I do too. Obviously, with the first identity, the above answer is very much $\Bbb{R}$ only. My first thought is that it isn't, after trying several methods to get the $\Bbb{R}$ case.

@geetha290krm$:$ I am now thinking about the same question. What a coincidence! Although it's quite natural.
